# Why would Vertica let me start a transaction if I can't roll it back?

Tags: transaction, vertica

I run the following statements against a Vertica database, one at a time:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE table
SET col1 = 'something'
WHERE col2 = 'something else';

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE col1 = 'something';

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

I run the first line fine... OK, now I'm in a transaction.

I run my update... OK, that worked.

I run my `SELECT` test to make sure things worked as expected... Oh wait, it looks like I missed a condition in the `WHERE` clause of my `UPDATE` statement.

No worries! That's why I did this in a transaction.

Let's rollback:

```
=> ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

[Vertica][JDBC](10040) Cannot use commit while Connection is in auto-commit mode.
```

Jones, hand over that roll of toilet paper you have on your desk.

So Vertica happily accepted my `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, knowing full well that very soon after that I would try to run either a `ROLLBACK` or `COMMIT`.

Yet, I can't! My connection is in auto-commit mode, so `ROLLBACK` and `COMMIT` mean nothing. My `UPDATE` was committed the moment it completed.

Did I miss something, or am I right in thinking this is just a very bad implementation on Vertica's part?

Why would Vertica accept a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` on a connection in auto-commit mode if the logical consequences (`ROLLBACK` or `COMMIT`) are illegal?

Comment: Bad implementation? If `AUTO COMMIT` was disabled, then you would need a `COMMIT` after any DDL.

Comment: @Kermit - I understand what auto-commit does and am not questioning its utility. I'm asking about a specific case--whether it makes sense to accept a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` in auto-commit mode when it is in fact being ignored, as I demonstrated. It's a matter of design, or user-friendliness, if you will. I think I was pretty clear about that.

Comment: I guess a better way to summarize the problem is this: By silently accepting the `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, Vertica is falsely implying to the user that they are within a transactional scope and will be able to roll back their actions. What Vertica should do instead, I believe, is fail loudly on the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` when the connection is in auto-commit mode to signal clearly that user-controlled transactions are not allowed.

Comment: What you're saying is in perfect accordance with Eric Raymond's "[The Art of Unix Programming](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/). If you succeed, do it quietly, if you fail, fail early and noisely.

Comment: I get it now. I agree you shouldn't be able to create a transaction if `AUTOCOMMIT` is enabled.

Comment: Which tool are you using to run this? Maybe that doesn't properly support the `begin transaction` thing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I'm using [DBeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/). The issue is with Vertica and not the client, in this case.

Comment: Well, the client needs to disable auto-commit once you start a manual transaction.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Oh, is that how it works? Would it be the client or the JDBC driver that does the disabling? The error rejecting the `ROLLBACK` seemed to be coming from the JDBC driver, so it seems like that same component should also be rejecting the `BEGIN` (or disabling auto-commit, of course). And I believe Vertica support conceded this point. So in this case, I believe DBeaver wouldn't be at fault since the JDBC driver is provided by Vertica. Does that make sense?

Comment: If the driver doesn't support that, it **has** to be the client ;) But why don't you simply turn off autocommit in DBeaver completely? Then you don't need to worry about `begin transaction` at all. You just need to make sure you `commit` properly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - My objection here was that Vertica accepted my `BEGIN TRANSACTION` but then rejected my `ROLLBACK` because I was in auto-commit mode. So clearly the component issuing the rejection (i.e. the JDBC driver? It's not DBeaver though) had enough information to either also reject the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` or to temporarily disable auto-commit. Neither happened, which is dangerous from a UX perspective. The workaround is clear (disable auto-commit), but I wanted to understand whether what I was seeing was a real problem or just a misunderstanding. I believe it's the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertica support have acknowledged this issue and are tracking a fix under VER-44735. The Vertica issue tracker is not publicly visible, unfortunately.

Vertica refused to characterize this as a bug and labeled it instead as a "new feature request", but regardless this should be addressed in an upcoming release.

Answer (score 1):

Vertica (actually, I think most if not all databases) behaves in this manner because the part that processes the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` SQL statement, namely the query parsing and execution engine, is not aware of the client AUTOCOMMIT setting. On the other hand, the client is not aware of the meaning of the string 'BEGIN TRANSACTION'.

The flow of control looks something like this, assuming the command line client `vsql` is used to run the example:

1. User starts `vsql` and connects to the database.
2. User enters `\set AUTOCOMMIT on`. After that moment the client (`vsql`) knows to issue an implicit `COMMIT` statement after each successful statement.
3. User enters `BEGIN TRANSACTION`. `vsql` does not recognize that string as one of its internal commands and sends the string to the server for processing.
4. Server recognizes the string as a valid SQL statement, compiles it, starts a transaction, and returns a successful result code to the client. Since autocommit is a client-side setting, the server has no idea about it.
5. Client, upon receiving the successful result code, issues `COMMIT` to the server.
6. Server complies and commits the transaction it has just started.

etc.

Comment: This is a good start at explaining things, and is along the lines of what I was thinking was happening. So what is happening when the rollback gets rejected? The client sends a rollback, it gets silently accepted as well, and Vertica rejects the auto-commit that follows?

Comment: For the record, this is not how SQL Server behaves, from what I remember. When you run an individual statement it gets auto-committed. If you start an explicit transaction, though, the server will respect it as you would expect.

Comment: In the autocommit mode each statement in effect starts a transaction, so issuing a `ROLLBACK` simply rolls back the transaction in which `ROLLBACK` is the only statement. The implicit `COMMIT` starts another transaction which immediately ends with that same `COMMIT`.

Comment: The error message is: `[Vertica][JDBC](10040) Cannot use commit while Connection is in auto-commit mode.` What is generating that message? I'm guessing it's either the server or some part of the JDBC driver, most likely the latter. Both of those pieces are written by Vertica. Since the component generating the error message is clearly aware that the connection is in auto-commit mode, shouldn't it be capable of raising a similar error when the client issues a `BEGIN TRANSACTION`?

Comment: I guess we're now drifting into the "opinion-based" territory.

Comment: Assuming we've understood the behavior correctly, I would count this as a clear case of poor design or user-unfriendliness and not a matter of opinion. The contrast with SQL Server's behavior, plus the fact that Vertica clearly knows the connection is in auto-commit mode but interprets the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement in such a pathological way, are proof enough of this. I'll ask Vertica's support about this to see if they agree. :)